# Python Pandas Simple Lookup - Stumped

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

A have a data frame with State Abbreviation and Full State Name.

How do I take a state abbreviation and `lookup` the Full Sate Name?  Its so simple but I just can't figure it out.

```
stateDF = pandas.read_csv("c:\\states.csv", index_col=0)

targetState = "AL"

fullName = stateDF.ix(targetState,"Full Name")
```

Comment: Do you just want `stateDF.ix[targetState]`?

Comment: yeah, should be closed brackets around ix: `stateDF.ix[targetState,"Full Name"]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
stateDF[stateDF['abbreviation_column'] == targetState]['Full Name']
```

Where 'abbreviation_column' is the name of the column where the abbreviation resides.
This will find all rows that have the targetState variable in the abbreviation column and return only the Full_Name value.